# A Link to my Google+ Profile

Tags: google-plus

Is it possible to get a link to my Google+ profile that I can send to anyone so they can see my profile and add me to their circle?

This is a very common feature in Facebook but I am not able to find it in Google+ at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Visit your own profile, and copy the URL. That's the global URL of your profile. It should look like this:

```
https://plus.google.com/100089984211197410017
```

[image: screen shot]

Or, right-click on that "Profile" icon and copy the URL.

Comment: There are several URL shorteners which will allow you to take that ugly string of digits and turn it into a much more human-readable URL. I use http://gplus.to, but there are others.